# Convert/Embed one expression tree into another

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lambda, expression-trees, iqueryable

EDIT: More detailed question.

I am working on batched operations in nHibernate, specifically for `In` queries to overcome the 2100 parameter limit size in SQL Server.

For this, I have created a class with this constructor (this is a very simplified version):

```
BatchedQuery(session.Query<Foo>(), allValues, (l, e) => l.Contains(e.Id));

...

public BatchedQuery(IQueryable<TEntity> query, IList<TValue> allValues, Expression<Func<IList<TValue>, TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
   List<TValue> values = ...; // Select a batch from allValues
   ...

   // I want to pass the values to the expression passed in...
   // something like this, without using Compile: 
   // e => predicate.Compile()(values, e)

   // using JKor's method, I tried this...
   ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");
   Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expr2 =
       Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(Expression.Invoke(predicate,
           Expression.Constant(batchOfValues), param), param);

   query = query.Where(expr2);

   // Do something with the query...
}

// Somewhere else..
// This causes the exception
batchedQuery.ToList();
```

The above is causing nHibernate to throw a `KeyNotFoundException`.
Here is the stack trace:

```
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
at NHibernate.Param.NamedParameterSpecification.SetEffectiveType(QueryParameters queryParameters)
at NHibernate.Param.ParametersBackTrackExtensions.ResetEffectiveExpectedType(IEnumerable`1 parameterSpecs, QueryParameters queryParameters)
at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Loader.QueryLoader.ResetEffectiveExpectedType(IEnumerable`1 parameterSpecs, QueryParameters queryParameters)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.CreateSqlCommand(QueryParameters queryParameters, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Impl.MultiQueryImpl.AggregateQueriesInformation()
at NHibernate.Impl.MultiQueryImpl.get_Parameters()
at NHibernate.Impl.MultiQueryImpl.CreateCombinedQueryParameters()
at NHibernate.Impl.MultiQueryImpl.List()
at NHibernate.Impl.FutureQueryBatch.GetResultsFrom(IMultiQuery multiApproach)
at NHibernate.Impl.FutureBatch`2.GetResults()
at NHibernate.Impl.FutureBatch`2.get_Results()
at NHibernate.Impl.FutureBatch`2.GetCurrentResult[TResult](Int32 currentIndex)
at NHibernate.Impl.FutureBatch`2.<>c__DisplayClass4`1.<GetEnumerator>b__3()
at NHibernate.Impl.DelayedEnumerator`1.<get_Enumerable>d__0.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at NovusERP.Data.Helpers.BatchedQuery`2.ToList() in D:\Short Utilities\Novus\NovusERP\NovusERP.Data\Helpers\BatchedQuery.cs:line 63
at NovusERP.Modules.Payroll.Attendance.AttendanceViewModel.GetEmployees(IList`1 selectedEmployeeIds) in D:\Short Utilities\Novus\NovusERP\NovusERP.Modules\Payroll\Attendance\AttendanceViewModel.cs:line 79
at NovusERP.Modules.Payroll.Attendance.AttendanceViewModel..ctor(MonthYear currentMonth, IList`1 selectedEmployeeIds) in D:\Short Utilities\Novus\NovusERP\NovusERP.Modules\Payroll\Attendance\AttendanceViewModel.cs:line 47
at NovusERP.Modules.Payroll.Attendance.AttendanceView..ctor(MonthYear currentMonth, IList`1 selectedEmployees) in D:\Short Utilities\Novus\NovusERP\NovusERP.Modules\Payroll\Attendance\AttendanceView.xaml.cs:line 18
at lambda_method(Closure , Object[] )
at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
```

Can anybody point me to the right direction? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Yogesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting my answer so that others can benefit from it.

The best way to do what I wanted was to use `ExpressionVisitor` and `Expression.Lambda` and make a copy of the whole expression with the appropriate changes. This class is an internal class in 3/3.5, so if you want to use this class for 3/3.5, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?ppud=4) is the complete implementation of the class. There are tons of tutorials available for the same on the net.

Secondly, anyone who wants to get a tool for parsing and visualizing expression trees should get the `ExpressionTreeVisualizer` sample in VS 2008. You will have to convert and compile the sample to VS 2010 for .Net 4.0. [This blog post](http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2010/06/08/vs-2010-and-expression-tree-visualization/) by Patrick Smacchia helps you how.

One side note to all of the above, nhibernate still throws the exception even after converting the query the way I have explained in this answer. This only happens if I try to convert the query to a future query and then evaluate it. Without converting the query to future, it works fine. I am searching for a solution for the same. I will update the answer accordingly if I find out why it is happening and what is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to make expr2 without compiling expr1 you cannot just use the built-in compiler conversion.  This is what you want:

```
Expression<Func<IList<TValue>, TEntity, bool>> expr1 = (l, e) => l.Contains(e.Id);
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");
Expresssion<Func<TEntity, bool>> expr2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(Expression.Invoke(expr1, Expression.Constant(values), param), param);
```

Comment: Thanks. Let got me going a bit. Is there any way, where I can just substitute `l` in the original expr`? I mean make expr2 without calling `Invoke`?

Comment: In theory you can, but you must re-create the whole expression tree and substitute in the value.  `Expression.Invoke` just creates an `InvocationExpression`.  For this exact example you could do this to do the substitution:
`expr2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity,bool>>((expr1.Body as MethodCallExpression).Update(Expression.Constant(values), expr1.Parameters[0]), expr1.Parameters[0])`
and remove the line that defines `param`